# Typescript Array type where output is all possible combinations of dynamic number of inputs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript

I'm trying to create a function that would create all possible combination of input parameters, keeping the output type.

For instance:

```
generateSets("string") // returns [["string"]]
generateSets(1) // returns [[1]]
generateSets("string", 1) // returns [["string", 1]]
generateSets(["string", "string2"], 1) // returns [["string", 1], ["string2", 1]]
generateSets("string", [1,2]) // returns [["string", 1], ["string", 2]]    
generateSets(["string", "string2"], [1,2]) // returns [["string", 1], ["string", 2], ["string2", 1], ["string2", 2]]
```

Basically i want a dynamic numer of arguments of unknown type (not always primitive), if the argument is an array I want to return all possible combinations of that argument with other arguments. And most importantly i want the return type to match the order of arguments like calling the function with string and then number I want the return type to be Array of tuples where first element is a string and second is a number.

I have tried this implementation, however it enforces that all the input arguments are of the same type

```
export function generateArgumentSets<T>(...args: Array<T | Array<T>>): Array<Array<T>> {
    const [arg1, ...rest] = args;

    if (!arg1) return [];

    const nested = generateArgumentSets(...rest);
    if (Array.isArray(arg1))
        return arg1.flatMap((arg1El) => nested.map((nestedArgs) => [arg1El, ...nestedArgs]));
    return nested.map((nestedArgs) => [arg1, ...nestedArgs]);
}
```

I tried another appraoch where i wanted to change the types of other elements but first, but that didn't work either

```
export function generateArgumentSets<T, T2>(...args: [T | Array<T>, ...Array<T2 | Array<T2>>]): Array<[T1, ...Array<T2>]> {
    const [arg1, arg2, ...rest] = args;
    if (!arg2) return Array.isArray(arg1) ? [arg1] : [[arg1]];

    const nested = generateArgumentSets(arg2, ...rest);
    if (Array.isArray(arg1))
        return arg1.flatMap((arg1El) => nested.map((nestedArgs) => [arg1El, ...nestedArgs]));
    return nested.map((nestedArgs) => [arg1, ...nestedArgs]);
}
```

Could you point me in the right direction to solve this?

Comment: Are you asking about types or the implementation?  Because as far as I can tell your implementation just returns empty arrays, at least when I test it.  Are you looking for something that makes the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of its input arrays, treating non-array inputs as single-element arrays?  But you seem to be focused on the compiler warning about heterogeneous arrays; this is easily addressed, but then the implementation/algorithm seems to be off-topic.  Where should I be focusing here?

Comment: I mean, is [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbkooW) what you're looking for?  That fixes both the implementation and the typings.   If that works for you I'll write up an answer; if not, please elaborate on what I'm missing.  (I could go even crazier with the typings so that tuples-of-tuples become cartesian-product tuples, but I don't know if you really need that)

Comment: [HERE'S](https://tsplay.dev/mA7o4w) the crazy tuple typings; probably more trouble than it's worth.  I'll probably write all this up as an answer unless you have some other issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're implementing the [**n-ary Cartesian product**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#n-ary_Cartesian_product) of your arguments, so I'll call this function `cartesianProduct` instead of `generateSets`.

First let's clear up the implementation (JS only):

```
function cartesianProduct(...args) {
  if (!args.length) return [[]]; // <-- note, [[]] not []
  const [arg1, ...rest] = args;
  return (Array.isArray(arg1) ? arg1 : [arg1])
    .flatMap(e => cartesianProduct(...rest).map(x => [e, ...x]));
}
```

The big problem with your original version is that you were returning `[]` instead of `[[]]` when calling `cartesianProduct()` with no arguments.  But that ends up collapsing everything to `[]` no matter what.

Let's verify that it works:

```
const x = cartesianProduct([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b"], [true, false])
console.log(x);
/* [[1, "a", true], [1, "a", false], [1, "b", true], [1, "b", false], 
    [2, "a", true], [2, "a", false], [2, "b", true], [2, "b", false],
    [3, "a", true], [3, "a", false], [3, "b", true], [3, "b", false]]  */
```

Looks good.  Now that we have an implementation that works, let's look at types.

---

A relatively simple typing which mostly does what you want is this:

```
type UnwrapArray<T> = T extends ReadonlyArray<infer E> ? E : T;

function cartesianProduct<T extends any[]>(
  ...args: T
): Array<{ [I in keyof T]: UnwrapArray<T[I]> }> {
  if (!args.length) return [[]] as any; 
  const [arg1, ...rest] = args;
  return (Array.isArray(arg1) ? arg1 : [arg1])
    .flatMap(e => cartesianProduct(...rest).map(x => [e, ...x])) as any;
}
```

Note that I'm [asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to `any` a few places inside the implementation since there's very little chance the compiler can follow the typing logic.  It's possible you could do something a little safer, but as long as the implementation is correct there's no reason to do so.

Anyway, `T` is the type of `args`.  The output type is an array whose elements are of type `{[I in keyof T]: UnwrapArray<T[I]>}`.  Generally, `T` will be a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), and so the output array elements will be a [mapped tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) of the same length as `T`; each property in the output tuple will be transformed from the corresponding property in the input tuple with `UnwrapArray<T[I]>`; if `T[I]` (the type of the `I`th argument to the function) isn't an array, you keep it; otherwise, you get the element type of the array.

Let's see if it works:

```
const x = cartesianProduct([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b"], [true, false])
// const x: [number, string, boolean][]
```

Great; the `x` variable is given the type `[number, string, boolean][]`: an array of triples.

That's probably enough for your purposes.

---

Still, if you're crazy enough, you could try to preserve as much type information as possible by interpreting the input arrays as input *tuples*, and then the output would be a tuple-of-tuples.  The typing is complicated and probably fragile, so I won't explain it much unless someone is really interested in seeing how all the parts work:

```
type UnwrapArray<T> = T extends ReadonlyArray<infer E> ? E : T;
type MakeArray<T> = T extends readonly any[] ? T : readonly [T];
type Concat<T> = T extends readonly [infer F, ...infer R] ? 
  [...Extract<F, readonly any[]>, ...Concat<R>] : [];

type CartesianProduct<T extends readonly any[]> =
  number extends T['length'] | 
    { [K in keyof T]: MakeArray<T[K]>['length'] }[number] ?
  Array<{ [K in keyof T]: UnwrapArray<T[K]> }> : _CartProd<T>;

type _CartProd<T extends readonly any[]> =
  T extends readonly [infer F, ...infer R] ?
  [MakeArray<F>, _CartProd<R>] extends [infer AF, infer CR] ? Concat<{
    [I in keyof AF]: { [J in keyof CR]: 
      [AF[I], ...Extract<CR[J], readonly any[]>] 
  } }> : never : [[]];

type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | symbol | object | undefined 
  | void | null | [] | readonly [] | {};

function cartesianProduct<T extends (N | N[])[], N extends Narrowable>(
  ...args: T): CartesianProduct<T> {
  if (!args.length) return [[]] as any; 
  const [arg1, ...rest] = args;
  return (Array.isArray(arg1) ? arg1 : [arg1])
    .flatMap(e => cartesianProduct(...rest).map(x => [e, ...x])) as any;
}
```

And now let's see what comes out:

```
const x = cartesianProduct([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b"], [true, false])
// const x: [[1, "a", true], [1, "a", false], [1, "b", true], 
//  [1, "b", false], [2, "a", true], [2, "a", false], [2, "b", true], 
//  [2, "b", false], [3, "a", true], [3, "a", false], [...], [...]]
```

The compiler knows exactly what type `x` is.  So it also knows this:

```
x.length // 12 according to the compiler
console.log(x.length) // 12

const y = x[3][2] // false according to the compiler
console.log(y) // false
```

Pretty neat!  And probably complete overkill.  I'd stick with the easier typings from before.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUIUkqJLAsgEoQYgAuAlgG40CeAyg2DBhACqsYDYAHMoefMWJ1ByAKrAA7gCcQMAILLVrADx8AfEgC8SPkggAPOhGAATcdRC2A9sAytN2ncIBmEZUgAooYA-EFIAFymANxEUj4ArsDwjK5I6MrWUAwgwAAKys62CSl65lY29ki5rADaALr6ABQAdG0gymJRfACUUZ4gurhItQDSSMJIANYQrM4+pvVRCipqA7p8Y41IAL6GBFJSDAtNAIQdYi28onQAFj1IyhB0CcrAIw311eI10UgA9P8kDoALQgkjOawAGg+9S+wEhI3qkkO6VcUDoIwuAEYYW0Wk8MV8TBcoLFUY9nq93k11i0GFB1k0cQ8wjjIljOtj6j0Wj5aHQALJqJrIIyGDJZHL5QrFFKtNqEui8sAiizGQy1CB4toWHkPEA-YCsclSHZxYjwdHOXhXZwiJqS6DSgpFEp0JoAIgxymEIk9PQegMpLze4lqtW9dF9ok9cJRluttow9sdHSluVdco92MDAKBT1DwHDtW5yMOVuLNogdodTuymdl7q9Pr9nphuaDBapYY+UZj-o78YrSZrKbr6edjbd8sjrdjMP7foATHGO3ng4XqSWlwukNyYXPoyv2-vh1JK1Bq7W05kpzKZx7d4ORrikMv9fmQ9u+-OXweRmfU8P3LC9RxvesXSbWcgMXP9V3qQ83w-DduyLHc-1PACjwHYDEMA+CsPwnCTxhECLTRYtMXVExIOnbMmlLMiYQAZmIz0QFPT0ACM1xGaMEm1JAfEwKAIB5BMv0vaiolqYAEjAbj-BhP8YW45xq1yeoGkky9r3HJoLB6U1iH+AAqD43w408BPEpDF04mERIwMTiKs3iYVstzFw84TRLspBJMOWplwcmzlEE4jQqQaynP8qKfPCyLD2injT2c1yoSCqRahYsLPIigLcvyvyXKKvKYt8rzDwqtK4rKuFiDM-5dPRaiLBoyyyOIiqABZiIAVhhAA2OETMojEkFYYx0knBsHwY-EOqM8bpKm8RaLmqDH0Y5CvkNEgFKU5QGhqmF+u+Q7FP8BpjLic0UVIaA4EQJAAGFnG4DAGHQaxbD4BIeH4QQ-XEAhJJkGB5CUVQNC0QY9EMEwzEsaw7AcCAnFcdx1m8YA-ACYIkDCQIOT4cbIeQYUZlxgwZpRip0cpLG3GmmoGmJ0wOSeFn3BGPh6gp2R3tcX7Efp8o0aqHmXFZkZfH8JAADEdXpfHFcoL4wlqfFAisVRShV5nZb59nGlVj7knoHRKH0L5ZMFijKferb6PdMpUcqcQZextnjQaJHsvk66Ak9pnNgAcmuEQ7gjr4AB88BGcZJhmOYFgFqJqYgWmtn0Woo5sGPbjj3Y5KO-wtey3HhjGCZ3jT+ZFmWGG1nhjY892QwogAfTe9Ms0R2IIeFvuB9lD3GelzGTb9uptiMbKGal72Z99+X1YCI38QVgJNeJ7Lamz3Glf0GEx8yQfba+MOqlqXekHUI2H7e-ewktsWDgpEYAEl6+mWYTcn5LCTrUFA-9G4LFfiA2oT9ag-3wrrfWCA6A6FfmA-CPs5ZmztrsLuHJgAQBYAEWSnxh6HGdgAOQ6IURQIBuK8Bmn+JAidg7HRYUgdSml3iJygKwRSNoOHOG4gAKwgCkDhSRbAQB8MICAtgOFMGcAwBRrCEgYAwBwjmicsF820XgHY5D4hJBSAwNIdEFru2Xl7JATRKEcMobdU6SB7G33ENQrQzg6EMIgM0fEpJuh9BdneeaWYrH7GyscWx5xOhQCuEXO4DwtxvFhPtI0JovygnBAiaEqSISYh0hSNatQcSqyVMSaosTxrEGSTSOkDImQsk5uyWSOIeR8gFMKGAooNSzRCdtRaipoDKhaKqbpNFNRCSWp+A6vxJIPValWZMqYLFhPlEBVC35ewRiAueRMSyxwrNdpY+UnYvy1JLGWRZV5lkTn6W7dZmF1xdi2cWX8x49xXJHAciCxy1kehInuZ8CFnnnJ7G8nZTyzyHmBURUC+ybmHLuRmE5T4oVMXfJ+Tc4KMIfP-OxKF5FvmIt+fc1FjFYIxUIt5TFmyLnvNwkOGFhKCV4tXEygibK8LImudRGaqzoIAuQqxNJE06AwscpVOMl1pKHlsvVVyMq2o9EksGNaFgojqtIVZSV1VXwlQykVdySUjWJQVUVVKurCoJRipKw1Nq6pID1SFM1pVMojFqla5KHqDXxUPPiYiAb4UTX0qmFaqqLIRh1SamlsU3WmqlQVb1GLHX2qyt-EYlqY0pV9Q1HNianXWvzamv12ViDFVtdmn1lbzU9Vdc62qvl7VfCQM1SSFh4k3FuF+bEy57qEB2EAA)